# How do I calculate PI in another base?

Tags: pi, radix

There are plenty of resources to calculate PI in decimal. I found this one to do it pretty fast: http://en.literateprograms.org/Pi_with_Machin's_formula_(Python)

But how do I calculate it in another base? Could I modify that code to do this?

Comment: The numbers will always be stored in binary. You can write your program in decimal, and print the result in decimal, but the actual computations run in binary. You could just as well print the result in another base.